# libGDX texture a mesh

Tags: libgdx, box2d, mesh

I need to understand how mesh works, and what are the parameters..
I looked over https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/OpenGLShader

But I don't really understand thoose vertex parameters..

Lets say that i have a polygon and I want to draw a texture repeatable, how can I do that?
I have the vertices of the polygon.
[image]

And also, for the mesh, the coordinates system is the same as libGDX system? ( origin (0,0) in bottom left ) ?

If I use mesh.setVertices() with the polygon vertices I can see nothing..

```
    shader.begin();
    shader.setUniformMatrix("u_worldView", camera.combined);
    shader.setUniformi("u_texture", 0);
    mesh.render(shader, GL20.GL_TRIANGLES);
    shader.end();
```

Comment: Nice images!  Can you show the `Mesh` constructor call and the `setVertices` calls you are using?  There are dependencies between these. (Its okay if they're just for a triangle and don't match the example image ...)

Comment: Also interested to see how this works. It gave me an idea for my game.